# Ordinal Encoding or One-Hot-Encoding

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable, ordinal

IF we are not sure about the nature of categorical features like whether they are nominal or ordinal, which encoding should we use? Ordinal-Encoding or One-Hot-Encoding?
Is there a clearly defined rule on this topic?

I see a lot of people using Ordinal-Encoding on Categorical Data that doesn't have a Direction.
Suppose a frequency table:

```
some_data[some_col].value_counts()
[OUTPUT]
color_white    11413
color_green     4544
color_black     1419
color_orang        3
Name: shirt_colors, dtype: int64
```

There are a lots of guys who are preferring to do Ordinal-Encoding on this column. And I am hell-bent to go with One-Hot-Encoding.
My view on this is that doing **Ordinal Encoding** will allot these colors' some ordered numbers which I'd imply a ranking. And there is no ranking in the first place. In other words, my model should not be thinking of color_white to be 4 and color_orang to be 0 or 1 or 2.
Keep in mind that there is no hint of any ranking or order in the Data Description as well.

I have the following understanding of this topic:

Numbers that neither have a direction nor magnitude are Nominal Variables. For example, fruit_list =['apple', 'orange', banana']. Unless there is a specific context, this set would be called to be a nominal one. **And for such variables, we should perform either get_dummies or one-hot-encoding**

Whereas the Ordinal Variables have a direction. For example, shirt_sizes_list = [large, medium, small]. These variables are called Ordinal Variables. If the same fruit list has a context behind it, like price or nutritional value i-e, that could give the fruits in the fruit_list some ranking or order, we'd call it an Ordinal Variable. And **for Ordinal Variables, we perform Ordinal-Encoding**

Is my understanding correct?
Kindly provide your feedback
This topic has turned into a nightmare
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just one thing to consider for choosing `OrdinalEncoder` or `OneHotEncoder` is that **does the order of data matter?**

Most ML algorithms will assume that two nearby values are more similar than two distant values. This may be fine in some cases e.g., for ordered categories such as:

- `quality = ["bad", "average", "good", "excellent"]` or
- `shirt_size = ["large", "medium", "small"]`

but it is obviously not the case for the:

- `color = ["white","orange","black","green"]`

column (except for the cases where you need to consider a spectrum, say *from white to black*. Note that in this case, `white` category should be encoded as `0` and `black` should be encoded as the highest number in your categories), or if you have some cases for example, say, categories 0 and 4 may be more similar than categories 0 and 1. To fix this issue, a common solution is to create one binary attribute per category (One-Hot encoding)

Comment: It made sense :)
Thanks a lot Kaveh

Comment: @Kaveh What are we supposed to do if the color variables has a large number of classes. For e.g say 10, if we one hot encode them, that'll increase the number of dimensions of the input data right ?

Comment: @Kishore You can still use one-hoe encoding. I think 10 as a dimension is not yet large enough to make you provide another solution. However, if you have a big number of categories, there maybe some alternative ways like [sparse data structure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/388051/328000).

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks! Now it make sense.