# Does sklearn algorithm assume ordinal integer values as continuous features or categorical features?

Tags: scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, ordinal

Assume that in a machine learning problem, there are several categorical features in dataset.

One common way to handle categorical features is one-hot encoding. However, in this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html), authors applied [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) on categorical features before model fitting and getting feature importances.

I would like to ask if sklearn algorithms, in general, treat OrdinalEncoded features as continuous or categorical features.

If sklearn models treat OrdinalEncoded features as continuous features, is it the correct way to handle categorical features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, OrdinalEncoded features are just numbers (float), so as *CutePoison* said, they are treated as continuous way.

OrdinalEncoded features is the correct way to work? It depends, you should ask yourself, **[the order of data is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052776/ordinal-encoding-or-one-hot-encoding)?**.

If its important, you can use `OrdinalEncoder`. Typical example is rating of a movie: `["disgusting", "bad", "normal", "good", "super"]`. As you can see, bad is "smaller" than "normal", so there an order importance.

However, in other categorical data like professions: `["police", "teacher", "lawyer", "engineer"]` there is no order importance. You can't say that police is "smaller" than lawyer for example. Then, you have to use `OneHotEncoder`.

So, as conclusion, it depends on how is your categorical data.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't make sense to convert a categorical feature to another categorical feature, when the issue is that you have a categorical feature.

If you read the inputs to the function you have:

> dtype: default np.float64
> Desired dtype of output.

i.e the output is a float as standard,

Is it the correct way? It, as all machine learning, depends on your application.